# Using custom method in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to be able to query for all clients with a `balance`.  I've defined balance as:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    def balance
        purch = self.purchases.map(&:total).sum
        pay = self.payments.sum(:amount)
        return purch - pay
    end
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    def total
        total = self.weekly_cost * self.weeks
        total = total * discount/100.0 if discount.present? and discount > 0
        return total
    end
end
```

where `total` is a method on the `Purchase` class and not a column on the `purchases` table.  I'd like to use it in a `where` query but obviously the following does not work as `balance` is not a column on my table:

```
Client.where("balance > ?", 0)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to store the balance on your database so you can query it and display it. You will be wasting resources making live calculations if you display the balance on your app, instead store it and save resources and your app will be faster. Use the next example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchases
    has_many :payments

    def update_balance
        new_balance = purchases.sum(:total) - payments.sum(:amount)
        update_attributes(:balance, new_balance)
    end
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client

    # Use some callbacks to update the client balance after save the record
    after_save :calculate_total, :update_client_balance

    def calculate_total
      total = weekly_cost * weeks * ((discount || 100) / 100)
      # I use update_column to skip the callbacks and only store the value
      update_column(:total, total)
    end

    def update_client_balance
      client.update_balance if client
    end
end


class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    # Use some callbacks to update the client balance after save the record
    after_save :update_client_balance

    def update_client_balance
      client.update_balance if client
    end
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but I've run into this question a few times where I'd like to use a custom method to query my database but perhaps it's just a sign I should reorganize a bit

Comment: For sure you will need to make some changes on your code base to get it working but it pays off. If you store the total of the purchase on your DB you will only need some callbacks to recalculate if you modify the weekly_cost, weeks or discount (this can be done on after_save or after_update) and after that update your client balance.  :)